# Stubbing JWT-Simple functions with Sinon

Tags: node.js, typescript, sinon, jwt-simple

I would like to be able to stub the encode function inside of the `jwt-simple` library.

Something like this:

```
import { encode } from 'jwt-simple';

sinon.stub(encode).returns('your encoded string');
```

Is this possible?
I have been trying to find solutions and workaround but have not been successful.

I'm open to ideas. Thanks

Comment: For a test? It's not clear in what context you're asking--if you want to stub the only function you're importing, why import it?

Answer (score 0):

The stubbing in your case be done simply by importing `jwt-simple` as reference.

```
import * as jwtSimple from 'jwt-simple'; // as reference

sinon.stub(jwtSimple, 'encode').returns('your encoded string');
```

Hope it helps